# In which library write writev and other functions that operate on socket like send also and where is the location of .so file

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, glibc, libc

I like to run this command to look for function names similar to sendfile, send, write writev on my some system library or kernel. command

```
nm -D /usr/lib/libopenal.so.1 //or T option
```

But I don't know where to look for these functions exact name the idea is I just run the above command with piping with grep so I can get exact names of functions like sendfile,

Someone told me then write may have name 64__sys_write which is king of correct, maybe its some other function so I like to know can I get this info on ubuntu linux

Comment: `ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.33-0ubuntu5) 2.33` kernel version 5.14.1

Comment: They're all in libc, wherever Ubuntu puts that these days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I don't know where to look for these functions

You don't need to *know* where to look, but you should learn how to find out answers to trivial questions (like this one) on your own.

Here are steps you could have used:

1. Select a program which exercises the function(s) you are interested in. In the case of `send`, `nc` and `telnet` seem like good potential candidates.
2. Verify that indeed the selected program calls `send`:

```
nm -AD $(which nc telnet) | grep ' send'
/usr/bin/nc:                 U sendmsg@GLIBC_2.2.5
/usr/bin/telnet:                 U send@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

Ok, suppose we are interested in `send` only, so `telnet` is our "target" and `nc` isn't.

3. Find out which libraries `telnet` uses:

```
ldd /usr/bin/telnet
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe957d4000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f2f2e2f4000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2f2e12f000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2f2dfea000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2f2e53c000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f2f2dfd0000)
```

The function `send` must be defined in one of these. Which one?

4. Run `nm -D | grep ' send'` on each one, to find that the function is defined in `libc.so.6`:

```
nm -D /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep ' send'
00000000000fee60 W send@@GLIBC_2.2.5
00000000000f3430 T sendfile@@GLIBC_2.2.5
00000000000f3430 W sendfile64@@GLIBC_2.3
00000000000ff520 W sendmmsg@@GLIBC_2.14
00000000000fef20 W sendmsg@@GLIBC_2.2.5
00000000000fefc0 W sendto@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

Bonus: you've found out that `sendfile` is *also* defined in `libc.so.6`.